# How to arrange a vector into an array?

Tags: r, vector

I have a vector with a series of values. For example, a vector with 100 values like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hr9cz.png)

And I like to arrange it to an  10x10 array with a special ordering like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uJC6.png)

What should I do with it? should I transpose or split vector first?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `as.matrix()` function. See the documentation with `?as.matrix` to employ it right.

Answer (score 0):

### Creating an example numeric vector (n = 16)

```
x <- 1:16
```

### Creating a matrix (4x4) from the vector, by row

```
m1 <- matrix(x,nrow = 4,ncol = 4,byrow = TRUE)

m1

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    2    3    4
[2,]    5    6    7    8
[3,]    9   10   11   12
[4,]   13   14   15   16
```

### Creating a matrix (4x4) from the vector, by column

```
m2 <- matrix(x,nrow = 4,ncol = 4,byrow = FALSE)

m2

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    5    9   13
[2,]    2    6   10   14
[3,]    3    7   11   15
[4,]    4    8   12   16
```